# how to parse file in bash shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to parse the lines in the file:
like :

0    0     0.00   0.20   0.00   5513      0.81     81

1    0     0.00   0.12   0.00    851      0.87     81

2    0     0.00   0.17   0.00   9485      0.76     79

3    0     0.00   0.13   0.00   3455      0.81     79

4    1     0.00   0.35   0.00    652      0.93     61

5    1     0.00   0.55   0.00   1730      0.97     61

6    1     0.00   0.40   0.00    389      0.97     55

7    1     0.00   0.33   0.00   1540      0.95     55

I want to use the values from the given columns, how can I extract these values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> use the values from the given columns

Let's assume the given column is the second column, you can use `awk` with

```
awk '{print $2}' FILENAME
```

where the `$2` represents the second column.

Answer (score 2):

For column 2

```
awk '{print $3}' input_file
```

Should give you

```
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
```

(I'm assuming the first value is a row name and you're not counting it as a column.)

Comment: That would be the third column, no?

Comment: Yes, and no.  I'm assuming the numbers at the beginning don't count as a column.  But fair point, that's confusing.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done as follows:

```
while read line; do
   set $line
   echo "idx: $1"
   echo "2:$2 3:$3 4:$4 5:$5 6:$6 7:$7 8:$8"
   # do whatever you want with the values here
done < test_data.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use cut command for this

cut -d' ' -f2 file

It will list the second column from your file.

In this way you can use for all columns.

I hope you would have understood.